# Laravel custom pivot usage (Extends Model or Extends Pivot)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5

I am really stuck using a custom model for my pivot, and don't understand why can we make a custom model for it if we can't use it as a model.
I've seen many answers and articles, and all chose to extend Pivot or Model, but real life usage is never taken into account and never go any further than giving it a "named" class.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
My main models:
**Player** model, with ***players*** table.
**Game** model, with ***games*** table.

**Player** and **Game** have a many-to-many relationship, that we can call "**Party**" with a "***game_player***" table.

Less important for now, I have also a **Score** model that holds the score/turns, a **Party** can have many scores, so ***scores*** table has a party_id entry.

So, here are basically my classes (Laravel 5.2):

Player

```php
class Player extends Model
{
    // The Games this Player is participating to.
    public function games() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class)->withPivot('id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    // The Scores belonging to this Player.
    public function parties() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Score::class, Party::class);
    }

    // The Custom Pivot (Party) creation for this Player.
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof Game) {
            return new Party($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

Game

```php
class Game extends Model
{
    // The Players participating into this Game.
    public function players() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class)->withPivot('id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    // The Scores belonging to this Party.
    public function parties() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Score::class, Party::class);
    }

    // The Custom Pivot (Party) creation for this Game.
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof Player) {
            return new Party($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

Party

```php
class Party extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'game_player';

    // The Player this Party belongs to.
    public function player() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
    }

    // The Game this Party belongs to.
    public function event() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Game::class);
    }

    // The Scores belonging to this Party.
    public function scores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Score::class);
    }
}
```

Score

```php
class Score extends Model
{
    // The Party this Score belongs to (has "party_id" column).
    public function party() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Party::class);
    }
}
```

Now, I have two different sets of problems that appear depending on if I extend Model or Pivot on Party:

1) When Party extends Pivot:

- Can't do something like **Party::count()**, anything that works with models.
- Can't do something like **Party::where("player_id", $player->id)** and so on ... Basically I want the party to have a scores/turns table attached to it and to do so I need to select the pivot model.
- Can't do something like $events->player->first()->scores() nor event $events->player->first()->pivot->scores(), it breaks with the following:

> PHP error:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

2) When Party extends Model:

- Can do trivial things such as Party::count(), Party::where("Game_id", $game->id)
- Lose all pivot functions, so can't do $game->players, not even $game->players() work: $game->players()->count() is correct, but $game->players()->first() or $game->players->first() will break with the following:

> PHP error:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

Question:

How to correctly use the custom pivot model when instantiating them is different?

I hope to achieve the following:

- Do the normal $events->players->attach($player)
- Be able to attach a score like $score->party_id = $events->players->find($x)->pivot->id (or any other way via a scope for example)
- Be able to count all parties being played, or the ones on one specific game or by a specific player (something like Party::count(), $player->parties->count() etc)

Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Can you show your migration file for game_player table? Does it have it's own id? or only the related tables ones?

Comment: I don't understand why extending Model with your Party class would cause `$game->players` to stop working. The players relation on the Game class shouldn't have any knowledge of the Party class. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EduardoPacios for the sake of testing, we can keep Game and Player as having ('id', 'name'). And Party as having ('id', 'player_id', 'game_id') ... So yes, Party has its own id (the thinking is that a player can play the same game many times ... Even if this can be changed to have a unique party and many scores representing the retries).

Comment: @programmerKev Well, when you extend the Pivot, you have to have the "newPivot" function in the two model, that's where they get the knowledge of the Party class, and I guess why it fails (the Party being instantiated as a Model not as a Pivot).

Comment: I see. Do you need to override newPivot? Have you tried leaving it out when having Party extend Model?

Comment: @programmerKev Honestly, I can't say if "I need/have" to override newPivot (actually wanted to have a unique pivot, so check if a party between player/game already exists, if not create, and in any case create a score and attach it to the party ... but I guess this can be done elsewhere).

Honestly, I think if we can give assign a class to a pivot, it was to simplify some work, so I don't have to write all the methods by hand (hasMany, belongsTo, etc i every model) ... But I'll try again and see.